# troubleshooting "Operand type clash: datetime2 is incompatible with int" on restore

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to restore our DEV database to my local sql server.  I am getting this error during the restore:

```
Operand type clash: datetime2 is incompatible with int
```

I have several 'tenants' with the same structure and only one gives this problem.

How can I get more details?
I need to know where this is happening?  A procedure, trigger, index, which table, etc.

The restore gets to 100%, then spins a while and gives this error.

How do I get more information?

fyi:  dev version is 13.0.5264.1 / local is 13.0.4001

Comment: Is this really happening during the restore? What is the SQL you're running?

Comment: Check your sql server log and see if you can find anything more there that might point to the actual cause. Also how are you restoring the database? Is this a restore command in SSMS from a .bak file?

Comment: Yes.  Restore from SSMS with a bak file.

Comment: Can you paste the SQL you are using/SSMS is generating please? Also, are there any server level triggers on the instance? If so, what are they?